# ¿Por qué no se ve una etiqueta <video> en algunos celulares y tabletas android?

Tags: css, html5, programación-móvil, video

inserto una etiqueta  en mi html y me la muestra bien en los navegadores de computadoras, pero en móviles solo la he podido ver a través de un Windows Phone y una tablet Samsumng, no he probado en iOS.

Este es mi código:

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" class="img-inicio" muted preload="auto" loop autoplay>
                <source src="vid/vid_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
```

Este es mi CSS:

```
.img-inicio{
width: 100%;
max-width:500px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema era el ahorro de datos que viene incluido con Google Chrome para dispositivos móviles.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo viendo tu codigo CSS tenias unos pequeños errores en le width

Aqui esta el codigo adaptado a diferentes pantallas solo le agrege una cosas mas si no las necesitas las puedes quitar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>VIDEO</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<style type="text/css">
 
video {  
   width:100%; 
   max-width:500px; 
   height:auto; 
}

</style>
<body>
<video controls preload="none" poster="parrots-poster.jpg"> 
   <source src="parrots.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
   <source src="parrots.webm" type="video/webm"> 
</video> 
<div>Note: informacion.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, igual me sirvio. Pero lo que causaba el conflicto era el ahorro de datos de los celulares con Chrome.

Comment: Oh  te entiendo, entonces porque no comprimir el video? @RenéErickSotoReyes y nota podrias agregar eso que comentastes   **conflicto era el ahorro de datos de los celulares con Chrome**

Comment: Cómo automatizar??

Comment: perdon equivocacion me refiero a comprimir

Comment: http://blogs.it.ox.ac.uk/adamweblearn/2013/10/how-to-compress-large-video-files-without-losing-quality-using-handbrake/

Comment: Porque es un vídeo pequeño de 8 segundos

Comment: mmm que raro, podrias usar mi codigo que te comente :)

Comment: Si, de hecho sólo lo muestra cuando pones los controles